# error for `recipes::step_num2factor()` - tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels

I get an error when calling `recipes::prep()` after having defined a `recipe()`, using the `tidymodels` approach. It appears that I misuse `recipes::step_num2factor()` during the recipe definition, but I don't understand what is going wrong.

## Load packages

```
library(tidyverse)  # data wrangling
library(tidymodels)  # modelling
```

## Provide data

```
data <- 
  tibble::tribble(
  ~Survived, ~Pclass,
         1L,      1L,
         1L,      2L,
         0L,      3L
  )
```

## Define recipe

```r
titanic_recipe <- 
  
  # define model formula:
  recipe(Survived ~ Pclass, data = data) %>%
  
  # convert numeric outcome to nominal (factor):
  step_num2factor(Survived,
                  levels = c("dead", "alive"))
```

## Prepping the recipe

```r
prep(titanic_recipe)  # THROWS ERROR
```

The live above throws this error:

```
Error: Assigned data `map_df(...)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 3 rows.
x Assigned data has 2 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

I don't understand why the error is raised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factor levels can't be zero, they should start with 1. So, you can add a `transform` argument to the `step()` function to add 1. The below modification worked fine

```
titanic_recipe <- 
  recipe(Survived ~ Pclass, data = data) %>%
  step_num2factor(Survived,
                  levels = c("dead", "alive"),
                  transform = function(x) x+1)   
titanic_recipe

prep(titanic_recipe) %>% juice()
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Pclass Survived
   <int> <fct>   
1      1 alive   
2      2 alive   
3      3 dead
```